Automatically Placing Picture in Cell
I hope anyone will help here for Placing the Picture in cell automatically. I have excel spreadsheet with multiple picture placing over cell. I want to place them in the cell. One option is to do it one by one but there are 500 of those. Second option is by using VBA code.
From VBA code I first tried to record macro which gave me the below result.
Sub PlaceAllPicturesInCells()

     ActiveSheet.Shapes("image12.png").PlacePictureInCell
     ActiveSheet.Shapes("image52.png").PlacePictureInCell
     ActiveSheet.Shapes("image96.png").PlacePictureInCell
     ActiveSheet.Shapes("image67.png").PlacePictureInCell

End Sub

So, to do it for all the images I used the following code but it is not working
Sub PlaceAllPicturesInCells()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.PlacePictureInCell
    Next shp
End Sub

Can anyone help here and suggest what went wrong?

try this:
Sub PlaceAllPicturesInCells()
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        shp.Select 'shape/picture must be selected first
        shp.PlacePictureInCell
    Next shp
End Sub

